# Retrieve a progress of index creation process in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Consider long-running query in `PostgreSQL` of index creation, smth like that:

```
CREATE INDEX some_idx   
   ON some_table   USING btree  
      (some_varchar_column COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

The question is: how to retrieve the progress  of this query process? Is it possible or not?

It is interesting to know the way in both cases:

1. using `pgAdmin`
2. using `SQL`
3. using some internal `postgreSQL` tools.

May be this additional info could influence on the answer: `PostgreSQL 9.3` on `Windows 7 64 bit`.

Comment: Not easily or reliably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Query_progress_indication) on this very topic, which links to several links. Their [accuracy is in question](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~gangluo/PI.pdf) as of a few years ago. There's also a [thread on hackers](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2006-07/msg00719.php) from 2006 or 2007 regarding adding progress indicators within which, EnterpriseDBs Greg Stark makes the same point.

Comment: Cool, looks like the very same topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In Postgres v12+ the view `pg_stat_progress_create_index` should give you this information.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/progress-reporting.html